# How does this function modify the other? (Higher Order Functions)

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

What is this code doing? How is it executing? What is x equal to?

Another useful type of higher-order function modifies the function value it is given:

```
function negate(func) {
  return function(x) {
    return !func(x);
  };
}
var isNotNaN = negate(isNaN);
show(isNotNaN(NaN));
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function `negate()` returns a `Function` object that, when called, will `return !func(x);` for whatever argument `x` is passed. This `Function` object is being stored in the variable `isNotNaN` with `func` bound to the built-in function [`isNaN()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN). In the next line the function object stored in `isNotNaN` is being called with the argument `NaN` (a JavaScript keyword). It is at this point that `x` becomes bound to `NaN`. The return value is passed to the function `show()` (which isn't shown here).

For more info, read up on JavaScript functions [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions) and consult the docs for JavaScript's [`Function` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) and [`function` expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function).

EDIT: Why do this? Sometimes it's useful to have a function that inverts a given boolean function. For instance, suppose you have some complex predicate and you want to filter an array for all elements for which the predicate is `false`. You can use `negate()` to turn the predicate function into a function that evaluates to `true` for those elements and just use `Array.prototype.filter()` to do the job. Think of it as a utility function that saves you having to write a lot of `function(x) { return !predicate(x); }` every time you want the inverse of a boolean-valued function. It's kind of trivial, but a lot of JS libraries (e.g., underscore.js, jquery, etc.) have a boatload of utility functions like this.

P.S. I would have written it more generally:

```
function negate(func) {
  return function() {
    return !func.apply(null, arguments);
  };
}
```

That way, it can be used with boolean-valued functions of an arbitrary number of arguments.

Comment: To expound, the negate function is fed a function and returns a function that will return the boolean negation of what the original function would return. This behavior is straight-forward when the original function would return a boolean value, but gets weird for functions that would return other values.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, now that you have described how this worked I realize i was probably just scared of the weird syntax. :) I still don't understand why this function is useful written as it is. It just seems like an extra step to call it.

Comment: Yeah, you could just negate the output of the original function. This is likely an example of a decorator pattern where a function is being passed to another function in order to alter its behavior.

Comment: @o_o So, is it like functional paradigm version of things like method overriding in OOP?

Comment: @o_o - Could you provide an example of a decorator pattern using this code? To me it seems this is a bare bones function that just has an extra step. That's something I never understand about articles on progamming... people try to make the code look sleek and cutting edge but forget that by excluding the logic that makes this more than a dumb function that returns another function that doesn't do much does not make the goal of this function obvious.

Comment: @TedHopp - Ah I see, so it's like a functional replacement for !   ?

Comment: So, a possible example might be something like: `function logger(fn) {return function () {console.log(arguments); fn(arguments)}}`. This function will create a new function whose behavior is "identical" to `fn` but it prints the arguments to the console, which might be useful for debugging. Try to think of other ways in which you could add to or alter the behavior of a function. Unfortunately, I'm on mobile and can't type up an answer with some fruitful examples.

Comment: @MarcCasavant - Exactly. I don't think I would necessarily write it like that for production use. I'd want to generalize it to be useful for boolean functions of an arbitrary number of arguments. But the structure would be pretty much the same.

Comment: Also, @TedHopp brings up a good point in that functions that take functions as arguments are rampant in Javascript. The functions `filter` and `map` are great examples.

Comment: @o_o - That's a pretty good example, but I'd add a `return` to the returned function so any value returned by `fn` wouldn't get lost: `function logger(fn) {return function () {console.log(arguments); return fn.appy(null, arguments)}}`. (Note also that you have to use `apply()` to pass the original arguments to `fn`.)

Comment: @o_o - he does have a good point and I do see those everywhere these days. I might still not be understanding how either example qualifies as "modifying behavior". What exactly does that mean? I think I might be assuming it's more like a mix in pattern where you're adding in functionality that wasn't there before.

Comment: @MarcCasavant - Don't get hung up over terminology. I wouldn't have described this as the decorator pattern.

Comment: @Ted Hopp - True enough terminology can be a hinderance to learning functional programming. If he has ES6 support he could rewrite that pretty conveniently with an arrow function! That would look cool, and that's how code should look... COOL.

Comment: Thank you both for your explanations, these will come in handy!

Comment: Yeah, the word decorator was used because I do a lot of Python and use decorators in a similar pattern, albeit, not for similar functionality.

Comment: Also, a `return` is definitely needed in the logger example, thanks @TedHopp, it looks like it's too late to edit the original comment though.